# How can i use "background-image" in Angular custom element?

Tags: angular, background-image, web-component

I'm trying to understand how can i use images from my repo in custom element (web component).

Here is simple codes of custom element

HTML:

```
  <div class="delimiter-container">
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.delimiter-container {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-image: url("../../../assets/images/image.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Main HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>UiComponentsAngular</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <script src="./dist/ui-components.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <delimiter-container></delimiter-container>
  </body>
</html>
```

Everything works perfect with Angular App, but not in standalone HTML.
So, how can i make a background using images in web-components?

Comment: Have you simply tried assets/images/image.png?

Comment: Yes, the image is not found